# Generating AMP CDN URLs

Tags: amp-html

I would like to experiment by linking AMP documents to other AMP docs.

I know I can lookup the CDN URLs using [ampUrls:batchGet](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/use-amp-url) but I've hundreds of thousands of URLs and I don't want to cache this huge mapping.

I can predict the CDN URLs using the schema defined in [AMP Cache URL format](https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/overview#amp-cache-url-format) and use that as the link URLs, but I haven't seen this approach recommended anywhere.

What's the downside of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: It's not recommended to use the cache in this way as AMP Cache URLs are only meant for usage inside an AMP viewer.

There are two main reasons why this is a problem:

1. Platforms, such as Google Search, surface AMP pages inside a viewer (e.g. open on a mobile device: https://www.google.co.uk/amp/s/ampbyexample.com/). One important feature of AMP viewers is that they display the AMP's original host. Depending on the AMP viewer implementation outgoing links will leave the viewer - even if they link to cached AMPs - and the original host will no longer be displayed. This is no problem as outgoing links usually lead to the correct origin. However, for links to cached AMPs this would mean that the origin would be hidden due to the lack of a viewer, which should be avoided.
2. AMP Caches only display valid AMPs. If you accidently break your AMPs, users will see an error message instead of your content. Invalid AMPs served from your own origin will still (most likely) show the content.

My recommendation is: if you want to experiment with AMP-to-AMP linking, link to AMPs on your own origin and let platforms decide whether they want to surface your linked AMPs from a cache or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll do the test using my urls.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "let platforms decide whether they want to surface your linked AMPs from a cache or not." Which platforms will display the cached document instead of mine?

Comment: AMPs displayed in Google Search results are served from the AMP Cache.